# Cant install ubuntu from partition

Tags: boot, system-installation, initramfs

I am currently having an issue with Ubuntu where i can't install any versions or distros based off ubuntu. If i try, it throws about 40 of the same error, stdin: Invalid argument, then goes to initramfs recovery shell.

Comment: I'd try to whipe the disk clean (Diskpart on windows or gparted on linux)
then be sure to select UEFI boot mode, not legacy, as (from what I've seen) ubuntu doesnt like it, while windows doesnt care

Comment: Ubuntu 'don't care' if you are booting legacy or uefi. But on a dual/multiboot system, all OS's must boot in same mode if you want it to work seamlessly.

Comment: That's just it though, i don't have anything beside gparted live.

Comment: Is this problem occurring before or after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Before. Ubuntu refuses to boot because it cannot locate the squashfs image containing the live filesystem